# Stop autosubmit on textfield

Tags: 7, views

I have tree element exposed on a View, two Select Box and a custom filter (textfield). I set up the View for Autosubmit (Automatically submit the form once an element is changed). For the two Select Box is OK but for the textfield is a problem because the page is submitting after every key up.

There is any options to do the textfiel stop the autosubmit behaviour on Drupal 7?

Comment: how did you get the view to autosubmit?

Comment: @Geoff On the View -> Advanced options -> Exposed form style -> Settings -> down below and check Autosubmit.

Comment: then as Patrick Ryan says in his answer, you will probably have to bypass that built-in functionality and use JS to accomplish it, so you can pick and choose which elements do and which do not trigger a submit

Answer (score 3):

Views depends of ctools and this is the cause of autosubmit.

On do: https://www.drupal.org/node/1735254

This is the feature what I need.

> If you want to exclude a field from the ctool-auto-submit-full-form
>   auto submission, add the class ctools-auto-submit-exclude to the form
>   element. With FAPI, add:
>
> ```
> '#attributes' => array('class' => array('ctools-auto-submit-exclude')),
> ```

Comment: Just adding the class has stopped the auto submit behaviour :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can do this through an existing Drupal configuration but it would be fairly simple to do with jQuery or JS.

**Remove the existing keyup event:**

```
$('.textfield').unbind('keyup');
```

**Modify it to submit on enter key instead:**

```
$('.textfield').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $('.your-filter-form').submit();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: this not work...